# Guardar valores de una consulta en php

Tags: php, pdo

Necesito esta ocasion, saber como guardar los valores de `c.cat_name`,`sc.idSub` y `i.numFile`, de la consulta, para usarlos mas adelante.

```
 $query1  = 'SELECT c.cat_name,sc.idSub,i.numFile from inventory_list as i
                inner join category as c on  id_category =fkCategory
                inner join sub_category as sc on idSub =fkSubCat where numFile = ?';
```

Comment: ¿Qué utilizas, msqli ,PDO,...?

Comment: Uso PDO @ReneLimon

Comment: edita tu pregunta agregando esos datos, tu pregunta es candidata a ser cerrada por falta de información

Comment: oka  @ReneLimon :v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saludos lo podrias hacer en un foreach de la siguiente manera:

```
$query = "SELECT c.cat_name,sc.idSub,i.numFile from inventory_list as i
                inner join category as c on  id_category =fkCategory
                inner join sub_category as sc on idSub =fkSubCat where numFile = ?";
$data = [];
foreach($DB->query($query) as $row) {
    $element = [];
    $element['cat_name'] = $row['cat_name'];     
    $element['idSub'] = $row['idSub'];   
    $element['numFile'] = $row['numFile'];
    array_push($data, $element);   
}
```

Explicacion, lo que hago es recorrer el array que me retorna mi query y voy agregando uno a uno los elementos en el array **$data** el cual contendra mi resultado deseado:

[image: posible resultado]

finalmente podrias obtener algo como esto, te sugiero revisar la documentacion de PHP:
[Array Push](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_push.asp)